# Hide/Show multiple objects in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How can I change visibility of multiple selected objects (let say paths) at once? Is there any shortcut for this?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If on mac, select the objects and press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>. Or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> if you're on Windows.

To reveal all hidden objects press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> (Mac) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> (Win)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works (I'm on Windows). But now I figure out that I have troubles making a selection of multiple objects from Layers Panel. I've tried Ctrl+Shift+Click which doesn't seems to do anything. Can't find similar shortcut for this action. Any suggestions?

Comment: In the layers panel: click to select one object then shift-click to select another object and everything in between it and the original object will be selected. To add individual objects to the selection use ctrl-click.

Comment: @venta7 Simply clicking on object names in the **Layers** panel will select those objects for interaction _within the layers panel only_ (e.g., moving objects to a new layer). To make a selection on your artboards via the layers panel, click the [circle next to the object name](http://i.imgur.com/zCGokpk.png). `Ctrl-Click` will select multiple elements, `Ctrl-Shift-Click` will select a range.

Comment: Any idea why this is not working for me?

Comment: This does NOT work for me on mac. Any other idea ?